# Need to return the name of person with maximum value from a column (fetched from database)

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = "SELECT firstname FROM candidate_info1 WHERE votes=(select MAX(votes) from candidate_info1";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // how do i echo the firstname of candidate with highest votes??
}
```

I'm new to PHP so please be gentle.

Here in the code I have to return the name of the person with maximum number of votes(stored in database candidate_info1), how do I do that?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use order by in your query.

Comment: This query is more efficient: `SELECT firstname FROM candidate_info1 ORDER BY votes DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: `$row = $result->fetch_assoc(); 
echo $row['firstname'];`

Answer (score 1):

Your query seems to be correct, since it:

- returns the `firstname`
- of the correct `table`
- for the record(s) which match in vote number to the maximum vote number

However, if you need a single value, then you can use an `order by` `desc`, as suggested in other answers. If you want to return the `firstname` of all the records having the same vote number as the maximum, then `order by` `desc` is inadequate here.

Also, if your problem is that `votes` is not stored in this `table`, but rather in a different `table`, then you might need to find the `group`s `having` the maximum count from there, selecting the `foreign key` and then return the values in your main query using the `in` operator. Anyway, if you have a specific problem which was not mentioned here, then you will need to add the details.

Comment: What do i do if there is a same number of vote count for different people? and can you please give me a brief about what the DESC LIMIT=1 does ?

Comment: @AshishSharma first, let me reflect on your first question. If you count the maximum vote number in a subquery and group by the vote number in the main query, filtering out lesser values in the HAVING clause, then you will get all the results you need.

Comment: @AshishSharma secondly, about LIMIT=1. This is syntactically incorrect. You might mean LIMIT 1 which means take all the results starting from the second element. You can read about LIMIT <offset>, <item count> in the docs here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $firstname=$row['firstname'];
}

echo $firstname;
```

In your query, you already return the name with the max votes so you just have to fetch the results in order to show that name.

Answer (score 0):

You have to fetch record By

```
$person_name = $result->fetch_assoc($result);
$person_name = $person_name['firstname ']
```